# Allow to match values with different formatting in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, safari

Values like numbers are typically formatted into a target locale.

Examples:

`1000000` quantity can be displayed as `1,000,000`.

`123456789` EAN code can be displayed as `123 456 789`.

When user press CTRL+F in a browser, the given substring is searched in the displayed page.

My question is: Is there any clever way how can listen to the native search browser action and return more results than the browser will natively found?

Example usecase:

Value is displayed as `123 456` and user presses CTRL+F and type `12 34 56`. I expect the browser to match the `123 456`.

Comment: I don't think there is. You could separate add the numbers in a `span` and separate them `margin`. Something like `p span:not(:first-child) { margin-left: 4px; }`